# How to set TableRow on bottom of screen by xml in android

Tags: android, xml, position, screen, tablerow

I have a problem with set TableRow on bottom of screen. If TableRows between button and GoogleAds are empty, GoogleAds is´nt on bottom of screen. I try almost everything. On left side in this picture (http://qkoment.php5.sk/image/image_screen.PNG) is what I have and on the right side is what I want.

and here is my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TableLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:id="@+id/TableLayout03"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">
      <TableRow 
         android:id="@+id/TableRow04" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:gravity="center">
         <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:background="@drawable/button" >
        </Spinner>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/TableRow05" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/tv1" 
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/blacky" 
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:gravity="center">
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/TableRow02" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center">
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/TableRow03" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center">
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:adUnitId="myID" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

thanks for every answer/suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. Why do you place your Ad in a TableRow?
With RelativeLayout you can place a view on the bottom of the screen with:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```